# How to publish Angular project?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, apache, gulp

I maked angular project. I used this generator:
 https://github.com/swiip/generator-gulp-angular#readme

I have serwer and domain. My question is: How publish this working project on serwer? Should I use Apache http?

Comment: Please be more specific with your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you used Gulp, you can check its docs to find out exactly you can build your Gulp application and deploy it to server.

On your command line run this in your working directory of the app

```
gulp    //to build an optimized files to be deployed on to the server
```

Now in your `dist` folder in your root of your working directory, you'll find all the files and folders that have been created by `gulp` task `default`.

Now you can deploy this on with Apache or node or Nginx or any other server you want. Simply paste all the files to the to the

> path/of/the/root/on/server

You can also preview your app the browser and watching for files changing and auto-reloading the browser to review changes by running

`gulp serve`

More grunt tasks [here.](https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular/blob/master/docs/usage.md)